# Smart commenting in an IDE (e.g. Netbeans)

Tags: java, comments

Is there a way to mark a line of code which you can afterwards easily find by color, click or something similar?

**Use-case:** Suppose I want to mark every occurence of the word "radius" as to investigate how many radii are used so that I can differentiate clearly which one is which. In this case I would want to go through multiple files and mark the lines with the occurence of "radius" and afterwards (having marked -let's say- 32 radii) smartly go through them.

I'm specifically programming with JAVA in Netbeans. But any other IDE or even language would also be welcome.

Comment: If you just search for radius, each occurence of the word will be highlighted. If it's the name of a variable you can also do a usage search.

Comment: suppose i have "radX23" of which I know it is one of the radii of interest. Or any other string which would not come up with a specific search.

Comment: Eclipse supports bookmarks, I'm pretty sure netbeans does too.

Comment: @omar I'm not sure I understand what you want - your question doesn't seem to match your comment. As commented above you can add bookmarks in Netbeans.

Comment: Very confusing. I am pretty sure, you can also search "fuzzy". Like search "rad*" ... or even regex - if i remember correctly - in Netbeans. https://blogs.oracle.com/roumen/entry/regexp_search_in_netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Both IntelliJ IDEA and Netbeans have a full project search ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> )

I don't know how Netbean's approach looks like, but IntelliJ lists all occurrences of the string you type in, letting you easily jump to any occurrence you select.

Comment: I of course use that already. The problem I want to tackle is: suppose i have "radX23" of which I know it is one of the radii of interest. Or any other string which would not come up with a specific search.